# How to view detail of a certain Item in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and trying to do a dummy project for learning purpose. This is my App.js which loads the advertisements and I want to click on the name of the indivisual advertisement to show detail of each advertisement like description and picture of it. Following is the code:

App.js

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      advertisements: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/advertisements.json')
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({advertisements: response.data.data});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    let advertisements = this.state.advertisements
      return (
       <Jumbotron>
         <div>
         <br/><br/><br/>
           {advertisements.map(advertisement =>
            <div key={advertisement.id}> 
             <h1>
                  <Link className='adName' to = {{pathname: `advertisement/${advertisement.name}`, query: { id: advertisement.id }}}>
                    {advertisement.name}
                  </Link>
                </h1>
             <h4>{advertisement.price}</h4>
            </div>
            )}
         </div>
        </Jumbotron>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is where I want to load the details of the advertisement.

Advertisement.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Advertisement extends Component{
 render(){
  const {advertisements, location} = this.props;

     if (!advertisements.length || !location) {
         return (<div>Loading...</div>);
     }

  const advertisement = advertisements.find(ad => ad.id == location.query.id);

  return advertisement?(
   <div>
    <h1> {advertisement.name} </h1>
    <h3> {advertisement.price} </h3>
    <h3> {advertisement.description} </h3>
   </div>
  ):(
   <div> Error </div>
  )
 }
}
```

This is my Routes.js for Routing.

```js
export default class Routes extends Component{
 render(){
  return(
   <Router>
    <div>
           <Navbar inverse fixedTop>
             <Grid>
               <Navbar.Header>
                 <Navbar.Brand>
                   <NavLink className= "nav-item" to="/">HamroBazar</NavLink>
                 </Navbar.Brand>
                 <Navbar.Toggle />
               </Navbar.Header>

               <NavLink className = "nav-item" to = "/components/About"> About </NavLink>

             </Grid>
           </Navbar>



        <Route exact path = '/' component={App} />
     <Route exact path = '/components/About' component={About} />
    </div>

   </Router>
  );
 }
}
```

Currently I am being redirected to : 'http://localhost:3001/advertisement/Laptop' with empty page with no errors.

Comment: how have you configured your routes? . it will help if you posted it too

Comment: @semuzaboi, I have updated my qn :) Please have a look.

Comment: where have you declared route for your `Advertisement` component ? or how is it getting loaded.

Comment: @Panther according to some of the links I have been through, it suggested me to get the id from Link like {{pathname: `advertisement/${advertisement.name}`, query: { id: advertisement.id } this and get props at Advetisement.js. That's where I am getting confused

Comment: you need to declare a route and point it to your component. Something like `<Route exact path = '/advertisement/:id' component={Advertisement} />`. Then you can get the `id` inside your component like `this.props.params.match.id` and use it.

Comment: @Panther, doesn't seem to work

Comment: where are you rendering the advertisements ? in the above code, you have not shown where you are rendering it.. Please edit the question to add the same.